# В UI Видны Пиксели

Tags: unity3d

Я загрузил картинку в UI Image и уменьшил её до нужных размеров, но у неё стали видны пиксели, хотя в редакторе всё хорошо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скрин приложите пожалуйста

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Готово!

Comment: Похожа что текстура очень большая, попробуйте поиграть с фильтрацией в свойствах (билинейная трилинейная)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q 128X128

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/822051/jagged-pixelated-edges-on-all-sprites.html

Comment: Фоток настроек текстуры пожалуйста, трилинейная фильтрация с мипмапами должна решить проблему.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Вот как раз вот это и помогло https://answers.unity.com/questions/822051/jagged-pixelated-edges-on-all-sprites.html

Comment: @AimonZ. отлично, можете оформить как ответ =)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Это конечно не по теме но можно узнать у меня висит на UI компоненте Aspect ratio filter как мне получить у rect transform переменную h Delta через скрипт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема в настройках канваса.

1. у тебя есть размер экрана девайса
2. размер экрана канваса
3. размер картинки

для того что бы убрать пикселизацию в даном случае тебе нужно порытся в настройках канваса и изменить прорисовку его размера в пикселях на большее разрешение.

Comment: На "другое" это какое? Больше или меньше?

Comment: конечно большее. Чем меньше разрешение, тем более угловатой будет картинка независимо от ее реального размера. Это же логично

Comment: Логично это было написать в ответе, а не вытаскивать клещами в комментариях.